# Failing communication with Bitcoin node: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: full-node

I use the cryptean's BitcoinLib to make RPC calls to a Bitcoin node on another computer. Seemingly at random, the connection fails and I get a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException with the error code Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. I don't know if this is due to a race condition on the port number distribution on the local machine or a bug in BitcoinLib.

Here is the complete stack trace

- 2018-08-15 08:48:12.5570 Fetching transaction from Bitcoin node,
  txid=3586d46be7bb1875fede4349849b89daf5ed73320979da211a54146c7bd90bfb.
- 2018-08-15 08:48:12.5831 Failed during communication with Bitcoin
  node.
- 2018-08-15 08:48:12.5831 An unknown web exception occured
  while trying to read the JSON response
- 2018-08-15 08:48:12.5831
  System.Net.WebException: Only one usage of each socket address
  (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted Only one usage
  of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
  permitted ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Only one usage
  of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
  permitted ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of
  each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
  permitted    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String
  host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of
  inner exception stack trace ---    at
  System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
  System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()    at
  System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
  request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
  System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()    at
  System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask 1
  creationTask)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask 1.get_Result()
  at
  System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
  request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
  at
  System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage
  request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean
  preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth,
  HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
  System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
  System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task1 sendTask,
  HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
  disposeCts)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()    at
  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    --- End of inner exception
  stack trace ---    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
  BitcoinLib.RPC.Connector.RpcConnector.MakeRequest[T](RpcMethods
  rpcMethod, Object[] parameters)
- 2018-08-15 08:48:12.5831    at
  BitcoinLib.RPC.Connector.RpcConnector.MakeRequest[T](RpcMethods
  rpcMethod, Object[] parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my server making too many simultaneous requests to the same node.  The computer making the requests imply ran out of ports to use.